# Regex problem with telephone number capturing part of ID

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regex for grabbing text on email for french number which is like this :

```js
(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}
```

Which work pretty well but if there is no phone number on an email it will grab part of the id of a Facebook page [www.facebook.com/leboncoin-1565**0575204105**27](http://www.facebook.com/leboncoin-1565**0575204105**27) and then I have people trying to ring that nuumber :X

In case it's not clear and don't want it, I tried negative lookahead and behind but without any success

See problem at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ob6LJH/3).

Note that the phone number could be anywhere not necessary at the beginning of a line.

Comment: You can create boundaries like `(?:\s|^)((?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4})\b` with a capture group or `(?<!\S)(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}\b` with a lookbehind. https://regex101.com/r/8kdc4E/1

Comment: Just insert a word boundary anchor before the zeroes...? https://regex101.com/r/v5ybe8/1

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
(?:(?:\+|\b00)33|\b0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/v8YawI/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      00                       '00'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    33                       '33'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0                        '0'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (4 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s.-]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '.', '-' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){4}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```